# JavaScript and HTML Formatting - Table Needs to Call Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a high-school student trying to make a proof writing program. I just need the JS function Edit() to send the value of the first text-box to the table. Any ideas? I know the code is messy, I'll fix it later.

Code:

```
<HTML>
<body>
<font size="5">
<p align="center">
<p1>Insert Given:</p1>
<div align="center"; id="Input1">
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='given' placeholder='Given Information'></input>
    </form>
<p2>Insert Statement<br>to Prove:</p2>
<br>
<div align="center"; id="Input2">
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='prove' placeholder='Statement to Prove'></input>
    </form>
<button id='Submit' Value='Edit' onClick="edit()">Submit</button>
<script>
  function edit()
{
       var x = document.getElementById('given').value;
       var y = document.getElementById('prove').value;
       document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML.value=var x
}

</script>
<br>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
<col Width="15">
<col Width="300">
<col Width="500">
  <tr>
    <th>Step Number</th>
    <th>Step</th>       
    <th>Explaination</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id='Test'></td>     
    <td>Given</td>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I might just need to fix the variable form. Is it supposed to be x, var x, var(x) or what?

Comment: So `document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML = x;`? (notice the lack of `.value` from this line)

Comment: Where do you see that? (Stupid question but for some reason I don't see that line)

Comment: I don't see it anywhere, I'm _suggesting_ you use the line of code I've written and you notice both the differences between that and the line you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `textContent` and not `var` keyword to read the `x` value. → `document.getElementById('Test').textContent=x;`

```html
<HTML>
<body>
<font size="5">
<p align="center">
<p1>Insert Given:</p1>
<div align="center"; id="Input1">
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='given' placeholder='Given Information'></input>
    </form>
<p2>Insert Statement<br>to Prove:</p2>
<br>
<div align="center"; id="Input2">
    <form id='user-input'>
        <input type='text' id='prove' placeholder='Statement to Prove'></input>
    </form>
<button id='Submit' Value='Edit' onClick="edit()">Submit</button>
<script>
  function edit()
{
       var x = document.getElementById('given').value;
       var y = document.getElementById('prove').value;
       document.getElementById('Test').textContent=x;
}

</script>
<br>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width:100%">
<col Width="15">
<col Width="300">
<col Width="500">
  <tr>
    <th>Step Number</th>
    <th>Step</th>       
    <th>Explaination</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id='Test'></td>     
    <td>Given</td>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

! just add onChange="edit()" to first input and a little change in test function.

```
<input type='text' id='given' placeholder='Given Information' onChange="edit()"></input>
```

and

```
function edit(){
   var x = document.getElementById('given').value;
   var y = document.getElementById('prove').value;
   document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML = x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var x` is used to declare variables. And you don't need to edit `innerHTML.value` (I think this doesn't even exist). You just have to edit `innerHTML`

So, replace

```
document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML.value=var x
```

with

```
document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML = x
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to do but this will works better:
       document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML =  x;

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want only to modify DOM and insert values I would suggest you to use:

`insertRow()` and `insertCell()` methods

This suggestion is based on this [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow),
and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/1yx577kw/) is a specific [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/1yx577kw/) for your case.

Definition and Usage

The insertRow() method creates an empty  element and adds it to a table.

The insertRow() method inserts the new row(s) at the specified index in the table.

Note: A  element must contain one or more  or  elements.

Tip: Use the deleteRow() method to remove a row.

For example a simple test would be:

```
function edit() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");   
  var row = table.insertRow(2);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);    
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("given").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("prove").value;
  cell3.innerHTML = cell1.innerHTML + cell2.innerHTML
}
```

Hope this helps!